# How to check Kconfig flag in C source code

Tags: c, linux, makefile, conditional-compilation, kconfig

I am new to Linux and Kconfig.

I have a config enabled in a Kconfig file as follows :

```
config ENABLE_MY_CONFIG
    bool "Enable my config"
    default n
    help
     Say Y if you want to enable my config
```

I don't have everything included here, but It causes conditional compilation of a `my_lib.c` C source file by adding this to my Makefile :

```
obj-$(ENABLE_MY_CONFIG) += my_lib.o
```

However, I have a test application for testing all my code which must be in one C file.

How can I call functions in my `my_lib.c` file and test only if `ENABLE_MY_CONFIG` is enabled, and don't call the functions otherwise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#ifdef CONFIG_ENABLED_MY_CONFIG` within the kernel C code.

If you want to test it outside of the kernel, you can likely write something to parse the `.config` file to see if it's set in there.

Comment: Thanks. But I won't be able to set this flag via Kconfig? I would have to modify both Kconfig and this #ifdef separately

Comment: When the kernel is compiled, the kernel does some trickery to define C macros for most of the KConfig variables with a `CONFIG_` prefix.   Thus, if `ENABLED_MY_CONFIG` is defined in the .config file, kernel sources will essentially be compiled with a `-DCONFIG_ENABLED_MY_CONFIG=y` flag set.  The actual mechanics will be dependent on the kernel version you're compiling.   (some kernels generate a file linux/autoconf.h for example, which is implicitly included in all kernel source files).  Note that if ENABLED_MY_CONFIG is set to `n` in the config, then no corrosponding c macro will be defined